# Meaning of ツッコミどころ多すぎ?

Tags: meaning, set-phrases, idioms

I've come across the phrase:

> ツッコミどころ多すぎ

In a book where the character was for a second time expressing annoyance at his colleague's reckless actions.

But I'm unsure of it's meaning since it appears to me that it might be idiomatic or a set phrase of sorts. I've come across the same string of words being used on the web but no explanation of it's use.

(If I had to guess, "being the straight-man too many times.")

Answer (score 2):

ツッコミ所【どころ】 literally means "place for butting in" or "the point of retorting". It refers to a silly point in the words the other person just said. For the meaning of ツッコミ itself, see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17870/5010) and [this](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BokeAndTsukkomiRoutine). This ツッコミ by itself does not refer to a person but refers to an action of 突っ込む.

ツッコミどころ(が)多すぎ(る) ("There are too many points of retorting") means the previous statement has so many funny points that the speaker does not know how to respond and correct them. This is one of the ways to describe how unreasonable and messy a statement is.