# Translation of the word ごった煮

Tags: meaning, translation

The specific context of this word is ごった煮です。

This sentence is prefixed by multiple other statements that I have translated to be about themself, ending in ものです。

I am confused about what exactly this word means in such a context, with the provided translations in dictionaries i.e jisho not seeming to make much sense to me.

The exact context is

> 悪役令嬢ものです。ループものです。勘違い恋愛ものです。**ごった煮です。**

Comment: Doesn't [hotchpotch](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/sentences-with-the-word/hotchpotch.html) make sense?

Comment: I personally haven't heard anyone use such a word to describe a person before, which is why I was searching for an alternate translation/meaning as provided by the answer below.

Comment: Wait, "describe a person"? Do you know this もの is 物/モノ rather than 者? What is your translation of the previous three sentences? This may be related to the source of your confusion.

Comment: The very first sentence before this is こんにちは, and the whole package reads somewhat similar to a diary entry or a monologue. I have it translated as ` I am the villainess. I am the one stuck in a loop. I am the one with a misunderstood love. ` Although I am somewhat unclear on that third sentence as currently I am not sure what it refers to. (The loop refers to how the protagonist has been killed and relives their life multiple times a la groundhog day)

Comment: Okay, so you've got the first three sentences wrong, and that's why ごった煮 didn't make sense to you :) Preparing my own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ごった煮 is just "hotchpotch" or "mishmash" as jisho.org says, but you've misunderstood the first three sentences. This -もの is not 者 ("person"), but a kind of suffix that attaches to a noun and forms a **genre** name. It can also refer to works in the genre. もの is also commonly written in katakana and in kanji (物).

- SF物
  works of science fiction
- 日常モノのアニメ
  slice of life anime
- 悪役令嬢もの
  novel featuring the villainess-as-a-heroine trope (somehow it's [popular](https://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E6%82%AA%E5%BD%B9%E4%BB%A4%E5%AC%A2#h2-3) these days in Japan)
- [ループもの](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE)
  [time loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_loop) story/genre
- 勘違い恋愛モノ
  I-am-being-mistakenly-loved-by-someone sort of story/genre (e.g., a commoner heroine loved by a prince who believes she is a princess)

So the whole passage is:

> 悪役令嬢ものです。ループものです。勘違い恋愛ものです。ごった煮です。
>
> This novel is in the 悪役令嬢 genre. It's (also) in the タイムループ gene and the 勘違い恋愛 genre. It's a hotchpotch (belonging to these three genres).

Text like this usually appears in a preface or a review. If it's really said in a monologue by a heroine herself, think of it as a "breaking the fourth wall" sort of joke.

Comment: I see, the full passage does seem to make more sense when you read it from that perspective, whilst I have your attention could I ask you to clarify a following passage 107回殺された悪役令嬢だろ、と突っ込まないでください。I am a bit unclear on the specific meaning of 突っ込む here

Comment: @zombunny The meaning of 突っ込む is just [this](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BokeAndTsukkomiRoutine) or [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17870/5010), but I don't know what 107 refers to here. Maybe it's a reference to another なろう小説?

Comment: Oh yes, I thought it might be that and now the meaning just clicked in my head. The 107 is a reference to the book's title being about a villainess who was 108回殺された, except technically the 108 death was an accident and not being killed so the main character is 107回殺された  so I think the author is acknowledging that and asking readers to stop pointing it out?

Comment: @zombunny Ah, her 108th death was not 殺された! You're right, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

ごった煮 is pretty much a meal where you simmer or boil a bunch of other ingridents together. ごった is from ごたごた which can mean things being chaotic, out of order and so on.

So, here it sounds like ごった煮 is refering to the characteristics of the author stated in the preceeding sentences like ingridents. It sounds like the author wants to say they are like ごった煮 or someone who is complex or has a lot of issues.